# What's the best way to model optional parameter to UDF in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

Looks like it isn't possible to have optional/default parameters with an UDF. This [jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11688) suggested to have two different UDFs for such use-case.

My code looks like this,

```
dataset.select(RecordProvider.getKeyUDF(sparkArguments.getDatasetArguments)(col(hashKeyName), col(rangeKeyName)).as("key"),
               RecordProvider.getValueUDF(avroSchema)(to_json(struct(dataset.columns.map(col): _*))).as("value"))
```

The UDF looks like this,

```
def getKeyUDF(datasetArguments: DatasetArguments) = udf((hashKey: String, rangeKey: String) => {
.....
})
```

In this case `rangeKeyName` can be null, what that means is a `rangeKey` column doesn't exist for the dataset. The function my UDF is registered to handle null for `rangeKey`.

I am struggling to get this done without an if, else around the entire `dataset.select` and have two UDFs. Is that the only way to do it? Also, I can't use functions (`val`) for my UDF since I am using currying, so I have to stick to methods (`def`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use when(condition, result1).otherwise(result2) too on the column itself. The lit() can be used to avoid NULL. Lit can be of any data type.

```
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
    dataset.select(getKeyUDF(when(col("hashKeyName").isNull,lit("")).otherwise(col("hashKeyName")),col("rangeKeyName")).as("key"))
```

Comment: I guess, this is closer to what I was looking for without having a broader IF-Else.

Comment: Yes i use it all the time like a case statement in sql.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a column with only null values when it doesn't exists. Alternativly, you can use an if-else to check if the column exists or not and replace `rangeKey` with a null column where it does not. This would allow you to use the same `UDF` in both cases.

Adding an empty column if it doesn't exist\s:

```
if (!dataset.columns.contains(rangeKeyName))
  dataset = dataset.withColumn("rangeKeyName", lit(None).cast(StringType()))
```

Using if-else:

```
if (dataset.columns.contains(rangeKeyName)) {
  // Same as before
} else {
  dataset.select(RecordProvider.getKeyUDF(sparkArguments.getDatasetArguments)(col(hashKeyName), lit(None).cast(StringType())).as("key"),
                 RecordProvider.getValueUDF(avroSchema)(to_json(struct(dataset.columns.map(col): _*))).as("value"))
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The empty col worked well, since I didn't want to make any change to dataset since it will affect my **to_json**, I used it in a slightly different way as below. 
`
var keyCols =  ListBuffer(dataset.col(sparkArguments.getDatasetArguments.getHashKeyName))
if(datasetArguments.getSortKeyName != null){keyCols += dataset.col(sparkArguments.getDatasetArguments.getSortKeyName)} else {keyCols += lit(null)}
`
Btw, being new to Spark I assume Spark will apply optimizations & I won't incur memory overhead with `keyCols += lit(null)` or in general with keyCols?

Comment: @Nisarg: No problems, happy it worked out for you. Regarding memory overhead I don't think that is a problem in this case.

Comment: You can also use `when(col("hashKeyName").isNull,lit("")).otherwise(col("hashKeyName")` to implement IF-Else condition. It can be part of the select statement itself and you needn't put a broad IF-Else. Please check my answer below.